# XML autowire acting werid

Tags: java, spring

I have a very simple Spring project. just 2 beans:

```
public class BeanX {

  private BeanY yy;

  public BeanX(BeanY yy){
    System.out.println("yy:"+ yy);
    yy = this.yy;
  }

  public BeanY getYy() {
    return yy;
  }
}
```

and:

```
  public class BeanY {
  }
```

my context looks like this:

```
<bean id="yy" class="com.paweljarosz.BeanY"/>

<bean id="xx" class="com.paweljarosz.BeanX">
    <constructor-arg name="yy" ref="yy"/>
</bean>
```

and finally I run the app using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

    BeanX xx = ctx.getBean("xx",BeanX.class);
    System.out.println(xx.getYy());
}
```

For some reason the console output is:

yy:com.paweljarosz.BeanY@3dd4520b

null

This means yy bean was injected but later somehow disappeared. How is this possible?

Comment: Your assignment is wrong... `yy=this.yy` should be the other way around `this.yy=yy`. You are now assigning `null` to the passed in argument, instead of assigning the passed in argument to `this.yy`.

Comment: I completely overlooked it,  thanks:)

Comment: @M.Deinum You should really start posting answers instead of comments, so questions can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is flawed.

```
yy = this.yy;
```

The line above in your constructor does exactly what it is told to do. It assigns the value of the `yy` instance variable to the passed in `yy` value.

However what you want is to assign the passed in `yy` value to the instance variable.

```
this.yy=yy;
```

Your current implementation simply breaks the assignment.